# Why does Pylance struggle with type deduction from TypedDict?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pylance

Consider the following minimal example

```
from typing import TypedDict, Dict


class DictType(TypedDict):
    val1: int
    val2: int


val_dict: DictType = {"val1": 1, "val2": 2}
val_dict2: Dict[str, int] = {"val1": 1, "val2": 2}


for key in val_dict:
    val = val_dict[key]

for key in val_dict2:
    val = val_dict2[key]
```

If you add this snippet to VS Code and have `Pylance` installed (Type Checking set to `strict`) you will see that the `val` in `val = val_dict[...]` has red squiggles, while the one in `val = val_dict2[...]` has none. `Pylance` complains about `Type of "val" is unknown`.

How is that possible, or why can't Pylance deduce the type?